# Desktop apps hang upon launch on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office, opera

I've been noticing a strange issue lately regarding specific apps (Opera and MS Office 2013) not fully opening when launched.

For example, sometimes I'll open up Word, it'll show the loading screen, and then freeze. CPU usage for the app will settle at 0, and I have to end the task and restart it. This happens about 10-15 times each day.

Same thing with Opera, though nothing shows up. As with an MSO 2013 app, no CPU usage, and I have to terminate it and try again.

In terms of specs, this isn't the greatest machine (Pentium Dual Core E6300 @ 2.8GHz with 4GB RAM running Win 8 Pro), but this isn't usual at all for this PC, as everything worked perfectly before, for quite some time. Now, we'll be getting new PCs soon, but I have to sort this issue out now as we have several in-house apps that rely on MSO to work.

I have re-installed Opera and Office, but to no avail. Have also checked extensions and add-ins for both Opera and MSO, removed all third-party ones to see what could be causing the issue. Also, to no avail. No viruses, no spyware, no malware.

Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

**Update** I'm now trying to repair the office install, but it's gotten stuck about 70% of the way, no CPU usage.

**HDD Update** Interestingly enough, Windows Optimization claims that the drive has 0% fragmentation, but Defraggler says otherwise, at 12%...

Comment: What about the health of the HDD?  The fact the installation is getting stuck tells me you have a hardware (HDD) problem

Comment: Health seems good to me - that's from a disk check. Any other ways I can check?

Comment: It is running low on space though, about 2GB remaining...

Comment: It could be that it has aged a bit, in which case no errors would show up...

Comment: Seems it was a fragmentation issue. The drive was only 1% fragmented, but that part evidently contained crucial parts of both Opera and MSO. This is definite yet - I'd like to continue testing. That said, I'll put up the answer when I know for sure.